# Rabbit MQ broker to broker protocol over firewall

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, firewall, amqp

I need to send messages in local RabbitMQ queue. Sometimes I wish that the messages in the local queue to be sent to another instance of RabbitMQ so that they will be treated. I would like to receive the acknowledgment when the message is processed remotely. What protocol used between 2 RabbitMQ and this protocol through it easily you the firewalls ? thanks